# WinAPI Polygon Deform on Rotation

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics

Got a bit stuck on problem with my polygon(square), it's deforming on rotation, tried standart function SetWorldTransform, but got disappointed. 
Rotation function is OK. Possibly, the main problem is in the error after every rotate.

```
int xCenter = 105;
int yCenter = 105;

POINT pnts[5];

square()
    {
        pnts[0].x = 70;
        pnts[0].y = 70;
        pnts[1].x = 140;
        pnts[1].y = 70;
        pnts[2].x = 140;
        pnts[2].y = 140;
        pnts[3].x = 70;
        pnts[3].y = 140;
        pnts[4].x = 70;
        pnts[4].y = 70;
    }

void Drawsquare(HWND hWin)
    {
        HDC hdc;
        HBRUSH hBrush;
        HPEN hPen;
        LOGBRUSH lBrush;
        hdc = GetDC(hWin);

        lBrush.lbStyle = BS_HOLLOW;
        hBrush = CreateBrushIndirect(&lBrush);
        hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);
        SelectObject(hdc, hPen);

        Polygon(hdc, pnts, 5);

        ReleaseDC(hWin, hdc);
    }

void Rotate(HWND hWin)
    {
        HDC hdc;
        RECT rect;
        hdc = GetDC(hWin);

        double pi = acos(-1);
        double ang = 45 * pi / 180;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            pnts[i].x = (pnts[i].x - xCenter)*cos(ang) - (pnts[i].y - yCenter)*sin(ang) + xCenter;
            pnts[i].y = (pnts[i].x - xCenter)*sin(ang) + (pnts[i].y - yCenter)*cos(ang) + yCenter;
        }

        GetClientRect(hWin, &rect);
        ClearScreen(hdc, rect);
        Drawsquare(hWin);
        ReleaseDC(hWin, hdc);
    }
```

Comment: You have `x - yCenter` and `y - xCenter`, is that correct?

Comment: X and Y Centers are the same, so problem isn't in this points, thank you for reply.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Store your points into custom point structure with doubles instead ints use this type instead of POINT for all the logic operations

```
struct PrecisePoint 
{
   double x;
   double y;
}
```

then copy them into POINT array right  before Polygon(hdc, pnts, 5);
you can add method like:

```
 precisePointsToPoints( PrecisePoint[] src, POINT[] dst, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinates are being rotated as floating point numbers, then coerced into integers for storing back into `POINT` structures. The truncation errors are accumulating and causing the distortion.